# Expand Ubuntu Filesystem on Hyper-V not going through

Tags: hard-drive, fdisk, disk-management

can you please help in letting me know the steps needed to increase the size of ubuntu hard drive. It is  VM, I increased the disk in hyper-V by 11G.
Inside the VM, when I run `PARTED Print` I see

root@chef-u16desk:~# parted
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 65,5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  52,7GB  52,7GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      52,7GB  53,7GB  1022MB  extended
 5      52,7GB  53,7GB  1022MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 **3      53,7GB  65,5GB  11,8GB  primary   ext4**
```

I followed some instructions in some articles here but was not successful. I tried the GUI but cant extend the volume. What is strange, in all articles, they mention that I need the name of the group of disks which is not the case
Doing `fdisk -l` it shows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 61 GiB, 65498251264 bytes, 127926272 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0ea54806

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 102856703 102854656   49G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       102858750 104855551   1996802  975M  5 Extended
**/dev/sda3       104855552 127926271  23070720   11G 83 Linux**
/dev/sda5       102858752 104855551   1996800  975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I tried `growpart /dev/sda 1`
I get

> NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by 2046 [fudge=2048]